# making __builtin__'s from your class attributes?

Tags: python, class, attributes, built-in

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.a = 2
...             __builtin__.a = self.a
...
>>> myclass = MyClass()
>>> myclass.a = 4
>>> a = 2
>>> print a
2
>>> print myclass.a
4
```

I would expect `a` and `myclass.a` to have the same value. Why don't they?

PS. Why you would use `__builtin__` like this is another question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python does not have references. Assigning a value e.g. using `=` [rebinds the name](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

If you want such behaviour you need a mutable object, e.g. a list with one element:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = [2]
...         __builtin__.a = self.a
...
>>> myclass = MyClass()
>>> myclass.a[0] = 4
>>> a[0] = 2
>>> print a
[2]
>>> print myclass.a
[2]
>>>
```

However, reconsider if you **really** want to put stuff like this into `__builtins__`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the logic behind it. You are right, I can see that lists/tuples/dicts work as I would expect, but I don't see how ints/floats/strings should behave differently.

Comment: `x = 1` binds the name `x` in the local scope to an integer object with the value `1`. If you now do `x = 5`, `x` is re-bound to a new integer with the value `5`. It does not modify the integer that was previously bound - so if you did `__builtins__.y = x` between those assignments, both names would point to `1`, but the second assignment only rebinds `x` but not `__builtins__.y` - so they have different values. The reason why it's different for a list is simply that modifying an object (e.g. assigning an item) does not cause any name binding.